# Creating Firebase users in a real time database via Google sign-in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a new user in a realtime database when someone authenticates using google sign-in. However, I have only come across the following method for creating users:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:...)
```

As users are signing in with Google, they don't have a password. How would I create a user in the realtime database after google sign-in without making them create a password?

Comment: The documentation is pretty good on the [Google Sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) and most importantly it states *After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is created and linked to the credentials*. Are you asking something different?

Comment: Hi @Jay, yes I am trying to create an additional user data structure in the Firebase "real time database" for purposes other than authentication

Answer (score 2):

for google sign in

```
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class YourClass {
    func signIn() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
}

extension YourClass: GIDSignInDelegate {
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        delegate?.signInError(error: error)
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user?.authentication else { return }

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
        accessToken: authentication.accessToken
    )

    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { [weak self] (_, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Error
            return
        }

        // Success
        // Here call the Firebase DB update to users.
    }
}
```

}

after your user registration you need create or update the record in the DB

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(email).setData(data)
```

in my case I'm using the value email as primaryKey for the users, and data is a dictionary with all values to storage.

Comment: I am using the realtime database not the cloud firestore. Do you know what the equivalent would be for the realtime database of: 
   Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(email).setData(data)

Comment: Hello @Vinteuil right in this case use Database.database().reference()

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])

self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)

Answer (score 1):

You should choose "firebase google authentication"  better then email and password .

see this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui

and this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on iOS see full code step by step [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin)